# How do $table->unsignedInteger('user_id') and $table->integer('usre_id')->unsigned() differ?

Tags: laravel, database-migration, eloquent

In https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/migrations, we find `$table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();` a standard example in Laravel.

But we also have `$table->unsignedInteger('votes');` in Column Types section.

Which way is preferred to say a `user_id` references to `user.id`?

How these methods are different? In all aspects specially from point of compatibility among database systems?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`unsignedInteger($column)` is just a shortcut for `integer($column)->unsigned()`:

```
public function unsignedInteger($column, $autoIncrement = false)
{
    return $this->integer($column, $autoIncrement, true);
}
```